# Flutter autoDispose riverpod StateNotifierProvider with disposeDelay

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```
final chatBeingEdited = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose
    .family<_ChatBeingEdited, String?, int>(
      
  (ref, chatId) {
    return _ChatBeingEdited(
      chatId,
    );
  },
  
);

class _ChatBeingEdited extends StateNotifier<String?>{
  _ChatBeingEdited(this.chatId) : super(null);

  int chatId;

  void storeChatDataObj(String message) {
    state = message;
  }
}
```

I require to hold some value (here 'message') that is available after this widget is disposed, but just for a very short time, so that the value is retrieved immediately after by the next widget that gets built.

How do I add the disposeDelay to this code?

Comment: Based on the links provided by @LeosLeo it seems that disposeDelay is no longer supported https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/1664#issuecomment-1264608563

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible but it is also planned to make this even easier in the near future. You can access a `keepAlive()` function on a `ref` of an `AutoDispose` Provider, calling that will stop the provider from auto disposing. To eventually dispose the provider state you close the keepAlive link:

```
final chatBeingEdited = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose
    .family<_ChatBeingEdited, String?, int>(    
  (ref, chatId) {
    final link = ref.keepAlive();
    final timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () => link.close());
    ref.onDispose(() => timer.cancel());
    return _ChatBeingEdited(
      chatId,
    );
  },
);
```

This would keep the provider alive, but puts it pack on autoDispose after the timer goes off (5 seconds).
When the provider gets disposed the timer should be canceled as it is no longer needed. ([Further read of the Future API for this use case and a generalized implementation can be found here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/1664))

This however is not exactly what you are looking for, as you want the timer to start upon there is no listener and not on the first call of the provider.
We can archive this with a different lifecycle hook than `onDispose` ([A good article about this can be found here](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-riverpod-data-caching-providers-lifecycle/))
By using `ref.onCancel` which is called when the last listener is removed. We start the timer at that point, cancel the timer when it is listened to again by `ref.onResume` and close the link of `ref.keepAlive` when the timer goes of:

```
final chatBeingEdited = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose
    .family<_ChatBeingEdited, String?, int>(    
  (ref, chatId) {
    final link = ref.keepAlive();
    Timer? timer;
    ref.onDispose(() => timer?.cancel());
    ref.onCancel(() => timer = Timer(Duration(seconds:5), () => link.close()));
    ref.onResume(() => timer?.cancel());
    return _ChatBeingEdited(
      chatId,
    );
  },
);
```

For a more in depth explanation i can recommend the article [linked above](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-riverpod-data-caching-providers-lifecycle/).

Also while this is absolutely possible, your description suggests that delaying the disposal for a fixed amount of time is not optimal and more of a workaround. What if for any reason the fixed time is surpassed because of an old device or bad connection? I don't know the rest of your code but wanted to mention that.